# PHP: image overlay, applying top image to bottom image only where bottom image isn't transparent

Tags: php, imagick

Have you googled? Yes, a dozen or more articles.

Have you searched SO? Yes, as I'm typing my question and several times before that.

Have you searched the PHP docs? Yes.

None of the information I've found address the particular question I'm asking.

When you visit a clothing site and make a color choice for, say, leggings, only the color of the garment changes. It's the same image, with a filter applied for just the garment.

I've seen this done before in PHP so I know it's possible. A base layer, the model layer, then the garment in grayscale with a transparent background. The next layer is solid color or a pattern with a transparent background and blended with the garment so that highlights and shadows are retained, then the blended garment layer is overlayed on the model, which is overlayed on the background.

I've tried with Imagick, GD, and a couple of libraries, but in every case the colored/patterned overlay isn't limited only to the garment: it appears as a floating block of color/pattern over every layer.

COMPOSITE_ATOP gets me partly there, but the shadows and highlights don't show through. How do I limit the overlay only to non-transparent pixels in the garment layer? What piece am I missing? (Image below)

I've included the Imagick code because it's more concise than GD, but I'm open to anything at this point.

```
<?php
// PHP8.1

$backgroundImage    = new Imagick('./img/background.png');
$shadows            = new Imagick('./img/feet.png');

$backgroundImage->compositeImage($shadows, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

$rightleg            = new Imagick('./img/right-leg.png');
$w = $rightleg->getImageWidth();
$h = $rightleg->getImageHeight();

$image = new Imagick('./img/right-leg-color.png');

$rightleg->compositeImage($image,  Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY, 0, 0);

$backgroundImage->compositeImage($rightleg, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

$leftleg            = new Imagick('./img/left-leg.png');
$backgroundImage->compositeImage($leftleg, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

if (true) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo $backgroundImage;
} else {
    $rightleg->writeImage('test.png');
}

// Clean up resources
$backgroundImage->clear();
$backgroundImage->destroy();
$shadows->clear();
$shadows->destroy();
$rightleg->clear();
$rightleg->destroy();
$leftleg->clear();
$leftleg->destroy();
```

[image: Final result of the composite as of now]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is to put the color over a copy of the target using COMPOSITE_ATOP: this has a mask-like effect where the color is limited only to the non-transparent pixels. With that masked shape created, you can then composite the gray original over the colorful masked layer to apply light and shadows.

```
$rightleg            = new Imagick('./img/right-leg.png');
$rightmask           = new Imagick('./img/right-leg.png');

$colorful = new Imagick('./img/right-leg-color.png');

// composite the colors over original element copy
$rightmask->compositeImage($colorful,  Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);

// now apply highlights and shadows using the original element
$rightmask->compositeImage($rightleg,  Imagick::COMPOSITE_BUMPMAP, 0, 0);
```

If there's a better way I'm open to hear it, but this worked for me.

[image]